# Detect objects that are touching

Tags: python

how one can detect two object contact. with python, for example, I want every sphere becomes the child of the cube it touches.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using [closest point on mesh](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=closest_point_on_mesh#bpy.types.Object.closest_point_on_mesh)**

Test code, assumes spheres are named "Sphere[.nnn]" and cubes "Cube[.nnn]"  If a hit from the sphere's centre to a point on a cube is less than the sphere's radius, then it parents them.

```
import bpy
from bpy import context

scene = context.scene
spheres = [o for o in scene.objects if o.name.startswith("Sphere")]
cubes = [o for o in scene.objects if o.name.startswith("Cube")]

for s in spheres:
    o = s.matrix_world.to_translation()
    radius = sum(s.dimensions) / 6 # sphere radius guestimation
    for cube in cubes:
        cmwi = cube.matrix_world.inverted()
        local_pos = cmwi * o
        (hit, loc, norm, face_index) = cube.closest_point_on_mesh(local_pos)
        if hit:
            v2 = cube.matrix_world * loc   
            # distance from global hit to cube
            l = (v2 - o).length
            if l <= radius:
                cube.parent = s
                cube.matrix_parent_inverse = s.matrix_world.inverted()
```

Comment: Thank you. the cube and the sphere was for example. if I have a more complex form a cube, it will not work.
your code gives me an error "need more than 3 values to unpack" on line : (hit, loc, norm, face_index) = cube.closest_point_on_mesh (local_pos)

Comment: What version of blender are you using?, closest point on mesh changed to include hit for 2.77 I think.

Comment: version of Blender: 2.76

Comment: Change to `(loc, norm, face_index) = cube.closest_point_on_mesh(local_pos)`
and just fudge in  `hit = True`  ... or better still upgrade.