# Why Drop to Ground addon doesn't work?

Tags: add-on

I have installed the "Drop to ground" addon. I have added the plane and renamed it to "Ground", took a normal cube and put on the plane some distance away from the plane. Then I selected the cube, <kbd>Shift</kbd> selected the plane and hit the button to the left - *Drop to ground*. It's giving an error and nothing is working.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
file "C........ addons\object_drop_to_ground.py", line 166, in execute drop_objects (self, context)  
file "C........ addons\object_drop_to_ground.py", line 108, in drop_objects hit_location, hit_normal, hit_index = tmp_ground.ray_cast(lowest_world_co, lowest_world_co+down)  
valueError : too many values to unpack (expected3)  
location : <unknown location>:-1
```

I have downloaded the addon from this new link https://gist.github.com/mhulse/571947fbe5ca16b7f2b7

Can anybody give me solution for that error

Comment: Similarly to closest_point_on_mesh in http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63361/15543 (see comment) ray_cast has  an extra return value as of 2.76ish that returns the success of the ray cast  https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.ray_cast  Note: this is also outlined in the gist link comments in your Q.

Comment: may i know the solution plz sorry i dont know the language section. may i know what i have to do. can u plz download the addon and tell me whats the solution behind it im using 2.77a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Object.ray_cast](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.ray_cast) changed in 2.77 to include a "hit" return value giving the success of the hit.

You need to replace lines 108 to 111 with

```
        hit, hit_location, hit_normal, hit_index = tmp_ground.ray_cast(lowest_world_co, lowest_world_co + down)
        if not hit:
            print(ob.name, 'didn\'t hit the ground')
            continue
```

Full edit here https://gist.github.com/batFINGER/820d385839a222e5a10c1b7f5cdbd0b7

Comment: i have download the zip file. In the zip file it contains folder and in that there is a file drop to ground but it does not have the extension. So i cant install it then i copied the text from the website and save with .py extension it installed successfully but when i click to activate now its give the error Traceback (most recent call last):
file "C........ 2.77\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py, line 330, in enable mod=_imprt_(module_name)

file "C........ 2.77\scripts\addons\drop ground.py", line 220 register()
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Fixed the filename, the indent is ok you may have copied a bit more than the code.  Try hitting the RAW button and using select all / copy on that page, or rename the file in the zip, or download zip again.

Comment: can u fix the problem for the new version for 2.78 and 2.78a also  i have installed but after few 2min it kick me out to the desktop